# Macro directives in C — my code example doesn't work

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to get the following piece of code to work:

```
#define READIN(a, b) if(scanf('"#%d"', '"&a"') != 1) { printf("ERROR"); return EXIT_FAILURE; }

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int stack_size;
    printf("Type in size: ");
    READIN(d, stack_size);
}
```

I don't get how to use directives with the `#` operator. I want to use the `scanf` with print ERROR etc. several times, but the `"'"#%d"'` & `'"&a"'"` is, I think, completely wrong. Is there any way to get that running? I think a macro is the best solution — or do you disagree?

Comment: Can you add an example of how you would do what you're trying to do if you weren't trying to generalize it in a macro? I'm not quite getting what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: please, don't do that: use functions.

Comment: Step 1: What error messages is the compiler giving you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should only stringify arguments to the macro, and they must be outside of strings or character constants in the replacement text of the macro.  Thus you probably should use:

```
#define READIN(a, b) do { if (scanf("%" #a, &b) != 1) \
                          { fprintf(stderr, "ERROR\n"); return EXIT_FAILURE; } \
                     } while (0)

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int stack_size;
    printf("Type in size: ");
    READIN(u, stack_size);
    printf("You entered %u\n", stack_size);
    return(0);
}
```

There are many changes.  The `do { ... } while (0)` idiom prevents you from getting compilation errors in circumstances such as:

```
if (i > 10)
    READIN(u, j);
else
    READIN(u, k);
```

With your macro, you'd get an `unexpected keyword 'else'` type of message because the semi-colon after the first `READIN()` would be an empty statement after the embedded `if`, so the `else` could not belong to the visible `if` or the `if` inside the macro.

The type of `stack_size` is `unsigned int`; the correct format specifier, therefore, is `u` (`d` is for a signed `int`).

And, most importantly, the argument `a` in the macro is stringized correctly (and string concatenation of adjacent string literals - an extremely useful feature of C89! - takes care of the rest for you.  And the argument `b` in the macro is not embedded in a string either.

The error reporting is done to `stderr` (the standard stream for reporting errors on), and the message ends with a newline so it will actually appear.  I didn't replace `return EXIT_FAILURE;` with `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`, but that would probably be a sensible choice if the macro will be used outside of `main()`.  That assumes that 'terminate on error' is the appropriate behaviour in the first place.  It often isn't for interactive programs, but fixing it is a bit harder.

I'm also ignoring my reservations about using `scanf()` at all; I usually avoid doing so because I find error recovery too hard. I've only been programming in C for about 28 years, and I still find `scanf()` too hard to control, so I essentially never use it.  I typically use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` instead.  Amongst other merits, I can report on the string that caused the trouble; that's hard to do when `scanf()` may have gobbled some of it.

---

> My thought with `scanf()` here is, to only read in positive numbers and no letters. My overall code does create a stack, which the user types in and the type should be only positive, otherwise error. [...] I only wanted to know if there's a better solution to forbid the user to type in something other than positive numbers?

I just tried the code above (with `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <stdio.h>` added) and entered `-2` and got told 4294967294, which isn't what I wanted (the `%u` format does not reject `-2`, at least on MacOS X 10.7.2).  So, I would go with `fgets()` and `strtoul()`, most likely.  However, accurately detecting all possible problems with `strtoul()` is an exercise of some delicacy.

This is the alternative code I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int stack_size = 0;
    char buffer[4096];
    printf("Type in size: ");
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == 0)
        printf("EOF or error detected\n");
    else
    {
        char *eos;
        unsigned long u;
        size_t len = strlen(buffer);
        if (len > 0)
            buffer[len - 1] = '\0';  // Zap newline (assuming there is one)
        errno = 0;
        u = strtoul(buffer, &eos, 10);
        if (eos == buffer ||
            (u == 0 && errno != 0) ||
            (u == ULONG_MAX && errno != 0) ||
            (u > UINT_MAX))
        {
            printf("Oops: one of many problems occurred converting <<%s>> to unsigned integer\n", buffer);
        }
        else
            stack_size = u;
        printf("You entered %u\n", stack_size);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

The specification of `strtoul()` is given in ISO/IEC 9899:1999 §7.20.1.4:

> ¶1 [...]
>
> `unsigned long int strtoul(const char * restrict nptr,
>
>    char ** restrict endptr, int base);`
>
> [...]
>
> ¶2 [...] First,
>   they decompose the input string into three parts: an initial, possibly empty, sequence of
>   white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function), a subject sequence
>   resembling an integer represented in some radix determined by the value of base, and a
>   final string of one or more unrecognized characters, including the terminating null
>   character of the input string. Then, they attempt to convert the subject sequence to an
>   integer, and return the result.
>
> ¶3 [...]
>
> ¶4 The subject sequence is defined as the longest initial subsequence of the input string,
>   starting with the first non-white-space character, that is of the expected form. The subject
>   sequence contains no characters if the input string is empty or consists entirely of white
>   space, or if the first non-white-space character is other than a sign or a permissible letter
>   or digit.
>
> ¶5 If the subject sequence has the expected form and the value of base is zero, the sequence
>   of characters starting with the first digit is interpreted as an integer constant according to
>   the rules of 6.4.4.1. If the subject sequence has the expected form and the value of base
>   is between 2 and 36, it is used as the base for conversion, ascribing to each letter its value
>   as given above. If the subject sequence begins with a minus sign, the value resulting from
>   the conversion is negated (in the return type). A pointer to the final string is stored in the
>   object pointed to by endptr, provided that endptr is not a null pointer.
>
> ¶6 [...]
>
> ¶7 If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected form, no conversion is
>   performed; the value of `nptr` is stored in the object pointed to by `endptr`, provided
>   that `endptr` is not a null pointer.
>
> #### Returns
>
> ¶8 The `strtol`, `strtoll`, `strtoul`, and `strtoull` functions return the converted
>   value, if any. If no conversion could be performed, zero is returned. If the correct value
>   is outside the range of representable values, LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX, LLONG_MIN,
>   LLONG_MAX, ULONG_MAX, or ULLONG_MAX is returned (according to the return type
>   and sign of the value, if any), and the value of the macro ERANGE is stored in errno.

The error I got was from a 64-bit compilation where `-2` was converted to a 64-bit unsigned long, and that was outside the range acceptable to a 32-bit `unsigned int` (the failing condition was `u > UINT_MAX`).  When I recompiled in 32-bit mode (so `sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(unsigned long)`), then the value `-2` was accepted again, interpreted as 4294967294 again.  So, even this is not delicate enough...you probably have to do a manual skip of leading blanks and reject a negative sign (and maybe a positive sign too; you'd also need to `#include <ctype.h>` too):

```
        char *bos = buffer;
        while (isspace(*bos))
            bos++;
        if (!isdigit(*bos))
            ...error - not a digit...
        char *eos;
        unsigned long u;
        size_t len = strlen(bos);
        if (len > 0)
            bos[len - 1] = '\0';  // Zap newline (assuming there is one)
        errno = 0;
        u = strtoul(bos, &eos, 10);
        if (eos == bos ||
            (u == 0 && errno != 0) ||
            (u == ULONG_MAX && errno != 0) ||
            (u > UINT_MAX))
        {
            printf("Oops: one of many problems occurred converting <<%s>> to unsigned integer\n", buffer);
        }
```

As I said, the whole process is rather non-trivial.

(*Looking at it again, I'm not sure whether the `u == 0 && errno != 0` clause would ever catch any errors...maybe not because the `eos == buffer` (or `eos == bos`) condition catches the case there's nothing to convert at all.*)

Comment: Thanks especially for that final paragraph. I _knew_ I disliked `scanf(3)` for some reason but couldn't put my finger on a concise reason why.

Comment: OK thanks very much, that solves a lot of my problems. May I ask one mor question. My thought with scanf here is, to only read in positive numbers and no letters. My overall code does create a stack, which the user types in and the type should be only positive, otherwise error. And then the user types in a random decimal, also only positive number which gets then transformed in binary, with use of a stack.

I only wanted to know if there's a better solution to forbid the user to type in something other than positive numbers?

Answer (score 4):

You are incorrectly encasing your macro argument(s), it should look like:

```
#define READIN(a, b) if(scanf("%"#a, &b) != 1) { printf("ERROR"); return EXIT_FAILURE; }
```

you use of the stringify operator was also incorrect, it must directly prefix the argument name.

In short, use `"%"#a`, not `'"#%d"'`, and `&b`, not `'"&a"'`.

as a side note, for longish macro's like those, it helps to make them multi-line using `\`, this keeps them readable:

```
#define READIN(a, b) \
if(scanf("%"#a, &b) != 1) \
{ \
    printf("ERROR"); \
    return EXIT_FAILURE; \
}
```

When doing something like this, one should preferably use a function, something along the lines of this should work:

```
inline int readIn(char* szFormat, void* pDst)
{
    if(scanf(szFormat,pDst) != 1)
    {
        puts("Error");
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

invoking it would be like so:

```
if(!readIn("%d",&stack_size))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

Comment: In the example code, argument `a` is given as `d` in the invocation so it should appear where you have `#b`, and argument `b` is given as `stack_size` so it should appear where you have `&a`.

Comment: In general, it is better to use functions than macros - with that I agree.  The downside of doing that in this case is that you lose the error checking that compilers like GCC can do on the arguments to `scanf()`.  In particular, with your `readIn()` function, there's no way for the compiler to spot the problems with: `int i; char s[20]; if (readIn("%s", &i) && readIn("%d", s)) { ... }` whereas ... well, you can't use the macro in the `if` statement like that, but GCC would diagnose the incorrect format compared with the variable type.  See `__attribute__((format(printf,n,m)))` etc.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf(3)` takes a `const char *` as a first argument. You are passing `'"..."'`, which is not a C "string". C strings are written with the `"` double quotes. The `'` single quotes are for individual *characters*: `'a'` or `'\n'` etc.

Placing a `return` statement inside a C preprocessor macro is usually considered very poor form. I've seen `goto error;` coded inside preprocessor macros before for repetitive error handling code when storing formatted data to and reading data from a file or kernel interface, but these are definitely exceptional circumstances. You would detest debugging this in six months time. Trust me. Do not hide `goto`, `return`, `break`, `continue`, inside C preprocessor macros. `if` is alright so long as it is entirely contained within the macro.

Also, please get in the habit of writing your `printf(3)` statements like this:

```
printf("%s", "ERROR");
```

[Format string vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_vulnerability) are exceedingly easy to write. Your code does not contain any such vulnerability now, but trust me, at *some* point in the future those strings are inevitably modified to include some user-supplied content, and putting in an explicit format string now *will* help prevent these in the future. At least you'll think about it in the future if you see this.

It is [considered polite to wrap your multi-line macros in `do { } while (0)` blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-mac).

Finally, the [stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) is not quite done correctly; try this instead:

```
#define READIN(A, B) do { if (scanf("%" #A, B) != 1) { \
        /* error handling */ \
    } else { \
        /* success case */ \
    } } while(0)
```

**Edit**: I feel I should re-iterate [akappa's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685619/macro-directives-in-c-my-code-example-doesnt-work/8685708#comment-10800398): Use a function instead. You get better type checking, better backtraces when something goes wrong, and it is far easier to work with. Functions are good.

Comment: There are worse sins than `printf("constant string\n");`, such as omitting the newline from the string.  The format string vulnerabilities arise when the user gets to control the format string.  So `printf(user_input);` is potentially lethal; that should be `printf("%s\n", user_input);`.

Comment: @Jonathan: I thought about suggesting `"%s\n"` for the format string, but that would break the common case of prompting. Of course, you'd still have to include the `fflush(3)` call for the prompt, but that's easily done in a function with the prompt. In my experience, though, `"constant string\n"` is _often_ replaced with a variable when part of it is becomes computed... just having a format string _present_ gives the hint that format strings need to be handled carefully. :)