# What's the meaning of ## in the define code in C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

```
#define DECLARE_DELETE_PTR(type) \
void DeletePtr_##type(string &operand) \
{\
}\
```

What's the meaning of `##` in the macro definition in C++?

what's the difference with the followed code?

```
#define MAKE_STRINGS(VAR) #VAR
```

it is only one #, but the former is two #

Comment: See (amongst others) [Macro directives in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685619/macro-directives-in-c-my-code-example-doesnt-work) for a discussion of stringification (with a single `#`, as mentioned in comments to various answers), and [C preprocessor and concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489932/c-preprocessor-and-concatenation/) for a duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It concatenates the value you pass through the parameter `type`...

```
DECLARE_DELETE_PTR(gremlin)
```

Would expand to:

```
void DeletePtr_gremlin(string &operand)
{
}
```

Comment: what's the difference with the followed code?

#define MAKE_STRINGS(VAR) #VAR

it is only one #, but the former is two #

Comment: A single hash does *stringification* (it takes your value and encloses it in double-quotes).  The double hash does *substitution*.  So, `MAKE_STRINGS(gremlin)` would expand to `"gremlin"`.

Comment: @Paddy: No -- the double hash does token concatenation, so (for example) `x##y` is pasted together to become a single token, `xy`.

Answer (score 3):

It asks the precompiler to concatenate two tokens.

```
#define DECLARE_DELETE_PTR(type) \
void DeletePtr_##type(string &operand) \
{\
}\
```

`DECLARE_DELETE_PTR(int)` would give :

```
void DeletePtr_int(string &operand)
             //^^^ the macro argument is int, so the precompiler replaces it here
{
}
```

Indeed, in the macro code, the argument `type` is concatenated with the rest of the command. If the macro argument is `int`, then it's just a simple subsitution giving the above result. Remember that since it's a pre-processor directive, it happens entirely at compile time.

If you're on linux, I recommand giving a look at the `cpp` command to try and understand better.

---

As for your second question, the difference is that it's simply two different operators.

Just as the name implies -> it turns its argument into a c-string (I've just tried that). For example :

```
std::cout << MAKE_STRINGS(Hello World) << std::endl;
```

would turn into:

```
std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl
```

Or, more interesting :

```
std::cout << MAKE_STRINGS("Hello" World) << std::endl;
```

becomes:

```
std::cout << "\"Hello\" World" << std::endl;
```

It appears it also takes care of escaping special characters, but I could be wrong - that comes from experimentation from 3 minutes ago.

Comment: Not strings - tokens.  The rules are actually quite stringent.

Comment: True - that can be confusing. I'll replace that, thanks.

Comment: what's the difference with the followed code?

#define MAKE_STRINGS(VAR) #VAR


it is only one #, but the former is two #

Comment: The one-hash operator converts the macro argument that follows to a string — stringification.  Completely different from token concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

The ## operator is used to concatenate two tokens. Here is an example:

```
DECLARE_DELETE_PTR(MyType)
```

// would expand into

```
void DeletePtr_MyType(string &operand)
{
}
```

Comment: what's the difference with the followed code? #define MAKE_STRINGS(VAR) #VAR it is only one #, but the former is two # –

Comment: Using a single "#" results in stringification. Have a look at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html