# Using macros inside a printf string in C?

Tags: c, macros, printf

Given 3 doubles x, y and z, I make a lot of such printf calls:

```c
printf("[%+-8.3lf, %+-8.3lf, %+-8.3lf]\n", x, y, z);
```

I then would like to have a macro of some sort to write something like this:

```c
#define FORMAT(x,y) "+-x.ylf"

printf("[%FORMAT(8,3), %FORMAT(8,3), %FORMAT(8,3)]\n", a->x, a->y, a->z);
```

But of course, the compiler sees %F as a special string and doesn't get my macro inside the string.
Is there a way to achieve what I want ?

Comment: The compiler doesn't do any parsing of strings literals, except maybe replace escape sequences like `\n` with their actual character representations.

Comment: Adjacent string literals get automatically concatenated, e.g. `"foo " "%d"` becomes `"foo %d"`. You can possibly use this fact to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using simple numbers as arguments to `FORMAT`

Your "something like this" code is close — but you need to use string concatenation (of adjacent string literals) and the `#` operator to 'stringize' macro arguments:

```
#define FORMAT(x,y) "%+-" #x "." #y "lf"

printf("[" FORMAT(8,3) ", " FORMAT(8,3) ", " FORMAT(8,3) "]\n",
       a->x, a->y, a->z);
```

This is similar to using the macros from `<inttypes.h>` for printing types such as `int64_t`, except with those, you have to provide the `%` symbol (and any flags):

```
uint64_t x = 0x43218765CBA9;
printf("x = 0x%.12" PRIX64 "\n", x);
```

#### Using macros as arguments to FORMAT

> Would there be a way to define my 8 and 3 values as macros too? Like instead of writing everywhere `FORMAT(8,3)`, I would like to write `FORMAT(X, Y)` where I defined above `#define X 8` and `#define Y 3`.

Yes, there is a way to do that.  Introduce an extra macro:

```
#define STR(z) #z
```

And invoke that on the arguments to `FORMAT`, as shown here:

```
/* SO 7531-4669 */
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR(z)  #z
#define FORMAT(x,y) "%+-" STR(x) "." STR(y) "lf"

#define Y 4
#define X 8

struct Point { double x, y, z; };

int main(void)
{
    struct Point b = { 7123.4567, 6234.5678, 5345.6789 };
    struct Point *a = &b;

    printf("[" FORMAT(X, Y) ", " FORMAT(X, Y) ", " FORMAT(X, Y) "]\n",
           a->x, a->y, a->z);

    printf("[" FORMAT(8, 3) ", " FORMAT(8, 3) ", " FORMAT(8, 3) "]\n",
           a->x, a->y, a->z);

    return 0;
}
```

This works and produces the output:

```
[+7123.4567, +6234.5678, +5345.6789]
[+7123.457, +6234.568, +5345.679]
```

It demonstrates that you can use simple numbers or macros that map to simple numbers as the arguments to this `FORMAT` macro.  What you can't do is have `#define Y 3` and `#define X (Y + 6)` — that will stringify `(3 + 6)` which isn't valid in a `printf()` conversion specification.  (Beware of making `X` too big; you can end up with spaces between your number and the following comma.  Experiment with `#define X 12` to see what I mean.)

The technique of invoking another macro triggers the expansion of the argument, which is often what you want.  See [How to make a char string from a C macro's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/195975/15168) and [Macro directives in C — my code example doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8685619/15168).  The Q&A [How can I concatenate twice with the C preprocessor and expand a macro as in "`arg ## _ ## MACRO`"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1489932/15168) is about token concatenation rather than stringification, but the issues are closely related, and the solutions are similar.

Comment: Would there be a way to define my 8 and 3 variable as a macros too ? Like instead of writing everywhere FORMAT(8,3), I would like to write FORMAT(X, Y) where I defined above #define X 8 and #define Y 3. I tried several things but it keeps getting read as "%+-X..." which is plain wrong

Comment: I found a way by defining my X and Y as string macros: #define X "8" #define Y "3" and redefine my FORMAT macro to #define FORMAT "%+-"X"."Y"lf" but I find it a bit ugly... Is there a prettier way ?

Comment: @renaldo_kurifu: Note that there is a more elegant way to handle 'macros as arguments to the FORMAT macro' — see the updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could adjust the macro to something like:

```
#define SPEC "lf"
#define FORMAT(x, y) "+-"#x"."#y SPEC
```

and call `printf` :

```
printf("%"FORMAT(3, 20), x)
```

It might also be a good idea to place `%` inside the macro.

The single hash (#), *"converts"* x and y arguments to string literals.

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/WbcTWjrGd)